# React / Typescript Could not resolve dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm

A create-react-app sites in `client`. It uses Typescript.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "typescript": "^4.1.3",
  .....
```

React app has it's own `package-json` and `node_modules`

```
My-Project
├── package.json
├── node_modules
├── ....
├──client
   ├── package.json
   ├── node_modules
   ├── ....
```

The root folder has it's own `package.json` and `node_modules`.

There is a library that uses Typescript as a dev dependency.

```
"node_modules/typechain/node_modules/ts-essentials": {
  "version": "6.0.7",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ts-essentials/-/ts-essentials-6.0.7.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-2E4HIIj4tQJlIHuATRHayv0EfMGK3ris/GRk1E3CFnsZzeNV+hUmelbaTZHLtXaZppM5oLhHRtO04gINC4Jusw==",
  "dev": true,
  "peerDependencies": {
    "typescript": ">=3.7.0"
  }
},
```

```
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   dev typescript@"^4.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@"^3.2.1" from react-scripts@4.0.1
```

This results in the above.

Is there a way to solve this WITHOUT using `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`?

Comment: Could you solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.